# Navigate in the same page using react-route-dom

Tags: reactjs, dom, navigation

I have a very long page with There main components `<Head/>`, `<Body/>` and `<Footer/>`
The header has a logo and a bunch of links. I want these link, when clicked scroll to that part of page which is inside the . I don't want to use refs. I want a react-render-dom implementation.
In the internet I could find the solution fo either navigate to a new page or render single component. I want neither. I just want to scroll to that part of my page. I also found a package called [react router hash link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) but I don't understant how to implement it.
App component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import Header from "./Components/LandingPage/Header";
import Footer from "./Components/LandingPage/Footer";
import Body from "./Components/LandingPage/Body";

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
   <div className="ParentContainer">
          <Header/>
          <Body/>
          <Footer/>
   </div>
   )
  }
}

export default App
```

This is the body component:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
 import Intro from "./Intro";
 import Oneweek from "./Oneweek";
 import About from "./About";
 import Features from "./Features";
 import Mentors from "./Mentors";
 import Curriculam from "./Curriculam";
 import FAQ from "./FAQ";
 import Experience from './Experience';
 import Stories from './Stories'

 export class Body extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="LandingPageBody">
            <Intro/>
            <Oneweek/>
            <About/>
            <Features/>
            <Mentors/>
            <Curriculam/>
            <Experience/>
            <FAQ/>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Body
```

Answer (score 1):

**May be useful:**

```
<a href='#cart'">Go to cart</a>

<div id="cart">

     "I am cart"

<div>
```

**Give the scroll behavior in your css...**

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```